# Is there a way to add a web.config value to xml documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

So I have a web.config value that I would access from the code behind as:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchAlgorithmEnabled"]
```

Is there a way to add this as a tag in my XML documentation similar to this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Search Algorithm Enabled: <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchAlgorithmEnabled"]%>   
/// </summary>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not return it from a readonly property definition in the relevant class and annotate that, explaining where the underlying value comes from?

Answer (score 0):

XML documentation is generated at compile time and is static.

The web.config value can change after the application has been deployed.

Perhaps you need a 'settings' or 'config' page which shows the value dynamically.